# Mouse wheel view rotation not working in 2.73

Tags: 3d-view

I am using the [Logitech G502 Gaming Mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg6Y2.jpg), when I try to rotate the view with the scroll wheel, Blender doesn't respond.  I recently updated to 2.73, but the mouse worked fine with 2.69.

Comment: Nice mouse. My guess is that the drivers and/or the configuration software for the mouse is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Does the scroll wheel/middle mouse button work in other applications?